# Pandas: Remove rows with column displayed in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Despite the confusing title, what I want is this:

DataFrame 1:

`i | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 
 1 | data1 | data2 | data3 
 2 | data4 | data4 | data6 
 3 | data7 | data8 | data9`

DataFrame 2:

`i | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 
 1 | dataA | data8 | dataB 
 2 | dataC | data2 | dataD 
 3 | dataE | dataF | dataG`

The code should remove rows 1 and 2 from DataFrame 2 because the value of *col_2* appears in *col_2* of DataFrame 1. The column is specific, the code does not need to test for all columns. So DataFrame 2 should look like this after the process:

`i | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 
 1 | dataE | dataF | dataG`

Comment: The questions in this site must be asked in English, not Portuguese

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in Portuguese

Comment: I just translated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do it. The key line is `~df2.col_2.isin(df1.col_2)`. What the `isin()` function basically does is go through the `series` (`df2.col_2`) and check each element, whether it is in the argument `series`: `df1.col_2`. It returns a series of `boolean` values, corresponding to the index of `df2`. Then the `~` in front negates this to get only what is unique (or not in) `df1`. Then use this to filter the original `df2`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                    ['data4', 'data4', 'data6'] ,
                    ['data7', 'data8', 'data9']],
                   columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['dataA', 'data8', 'dataB'],
                    ['dataC', 'data2', 'dataD'] ,
                    ['dataE', 'dataF', 'dataG']],
                   columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'])
keep = ~df2.col_2.isin(df1.col_2)
df = df2[keep]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the mask using negation of `isin`

```
df3 = df2[~df2.col_2.isin(df1.col_2)]

Out[942]:
   i  col_1  col_2  col_3
2  3  dataE  dataF  dataG
```